# How do I make this 'monster fight simulator' work?

Tags: java, class, methods, simulator

As it stands now, console allows me to compile, but not to run it, it says:
"Error: Could not find or load main class MonsterFight"

Here is the code:

```
class Fight {

    Random rand= new Random();

    int Hit (int x) {
        int numHit = rand.nextInt(100);
        return (int) x - numHit;
    }


class MonsterFight {
    public void main(String [] args){
        String name;
        int hp = 1000;

        System.out.println("You start at 1000 Hitpoints.");
        Fight battle = new Fight();

        while (hp != 0)  {
            hp = Hit(hp);
            System.out.println("You have now " + hp + " hitpoints.");
        }
    }
}

}
```

I can't seem to make it work. All help appreciated, also tips to make this cleaner are also appreciated, as I am fairly new to Java.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the main method `static` and make `MonsterFight` a top level class (since static methods can only be declared in the latter):

```
class MonsterFight {
    public static void main(String [] args){
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make MonsterFight  as a public outer class and main method signature should be

```
 public static  void main(String [] args){
```

**NOTE:** have appropriate condition for while Loop

Try this

```
import java.util.Random;

class Fight {
   static  int Hit (int x) {
       Random rand= new Random();
        int numHit = rand.nextInt(100);
        return (int) x - numHit;
    }

}

public class MonsterFight {
    public static  void main(String [] args){
        String name;
        int hp = 1000;

        System.out.println("You start at 1000 Hitpoints.");
        Fight battle = new Fight();

        while (hp != 0)  {
            hp = Fight.Hit(hp);
            System.out.println("You have now " + hp + " hitpoints.");
        }
    }
}
```